# How to change title of home page in wordpress 3.4.2?

Tags: wordpress, html, title

Which file needs to be updated for changing the title of home page in wordpress 3.4.2?

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities...

1. You can change it in the Settings panel in your admin
2. You can change it from the header.php in the root of your theme.

I'd start with number 1 as most themes will update from the Settings panel.